# Kali linux 2020.2 have white screen and icons not showing after update

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, upgrade, shutdown, icons

I updated my virtual machine from kali 2020.1  to  kali 2020.2 using  apt-get upgrade  command in the terminal and it completed successfully.  Suddenly I got power-cut and I am also not saved the machine state. After I booted up the virtual machine and checked it shows like some sort of stuck white screen and icons are not showing. If I tried to open any program or terminal, it wont open.

Please check for attached screenshot for reference.[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe you still had some missing installation when you had a power cut or the newly installed upgrades were not done setting up.

I would advise you again run `apt upgrade`, if you get any error message like:

```
E: dpkg was interrrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

then I'll suggest you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` from your terminal, in case your terminal also refuses to open, you can run it on *MATE Terminal*, it would later prompt you:

```
Configuration file 'etc/mine.types' 
==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation. 
==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version. 
 What would you like to do about it ? Your options are: 
  Y or I : install the package maintainer's version 
  N or O : keep your currently-installed version 
    D    : show the differences between the versions
    Z    : start a shell to examine the situation 
The default action is to keep your current version. 
*** mine.types (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N ?]
```

You can select **Y** or **I** to install and finish the setting up of the upgrade

or

**N** or **O** to revert to you current version.

This should fix your issue.